# Lagrange function

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

Could you explain me the following step? I am supposed to mimimize $||Y-X\beta||^{2}$ subject to $K\beta=r $. The Lagrangian function is $L= (Y-X\beta)^{T}(Y-X\beta) + 2\lambda ^{T}(K\beta -r)$. I am confused why there is $2$ next to Lagrange multiplier?

Comment: Well I think that is notation to simplify calculation in the next step. Think of $2 \lambda$ to be a regulariser equal to $\mu$. It is just how you define that constant.

Comment: yes, it is a part of task, where one of the next steps works with fraction $\frac {1}{2}$ so they put $2$ in front of the multiplier not to work with fractions. However, i do not understand how it is possible, because it changes the value of lagrange multiplier and all other  values in the lagranga function.

Comment: Well it is just like renaming the variable (akin to variable substitution in integration). As a simple exercise, try to solve the optimization problem with $\mu$ as the regularizer (like you would have) and then in the final expression replace $\mu$ with $2 \lambda$. You will obtain all the same expressions.

Comment: I understand this, it is clear. However, they do not replace it and use substitution, they just put it there like this.

Comment: There is nothing sacrosanct about that choice of constant while defining the Lagrangian function. The basic idea behind the function is as follows: If you are minimizing $f(x)$ wrt to constraints $g(x) = 0$, then at optimal point, the gradients are collinear, that is, *there exists some constant* $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ for which $\nabla f(x) = \lambda \nabla g(x)$. Thus, if we consider a function $L(\mu, x) = f(x) + \mu g(x)$, then this gradient of this function will be zero at an optimum point, $x^*$ with $\mu = \lambda$. Thus, that specific construction is not sacrosanct. Does this help?

Comment: Note that you could also use $r-K\beta$ rather than $K\beta-r$ in the Lagrangian and this would flip the sign of the Lagrange multiplier.

Comment: Just to make sure. Let us say we have the problem
$$\min(\text{or}\max) f(x)$$ subject to
$$p^{t}x=b$$
in some textbooks, I saw the Lagrange function in the form:
$$L(x,\lambda)=f(x)+\lambda (p^{t}x-b)$$ $$L(x,\lambda)=f(x)-\lambda (p^{t}x-b)$$ $$L(x,\lambda)=f(x)+\lambda (b-p^{t}x)$$ $$L(x,\lambda)=f(x)+\lambda (b-p^{t}x).$$ So I can use any of these four form any time, it is up to me then.